# Find the maximum value of $a+b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, optimization, contest-math

The question:

> Find the maximum possible value of $a+b$ if $a$ and $b$ are different non-negative real numbers that fulfill
>   $$a+\sqrt{b} = b + \sqrt{a}$$

Without loss of generality let us assume that $a\gt b$. I rearrange the equation to get $$a - \sqrt{a} = b - \sqrt{b}$$

If $f(x)= x - \sqrt{x},$ then we are trying to solve $f(a)=f(b).$ Using some simple calculus I found that the turning point of $f(x)$ is $(\frac{1}{4}, -\frac{1}{4})$. Hence $0 \le b \le \frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{4} \le a \le 1$. From here, I have no idea how to proceed.

I used trial and error to find that when $a$ increases, the value of $a+b$ increases as well. Hence I hypothesise that $a+b$ is at a maximum when $a=1$ and $b=0$, which implies that $a+b=1$ is a maximum. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Please delete this question, as AMOC Senior Contest is still ongoing for some people (I know someone who couldn't do it today, for example). The form you signed explicitly stated that the questions would not be discussed online until after August 26th.

Comment: @SharkyKesa I had no idea this was from the Senior Contest! This was given to me from a friend. I cannot delete it now - what should I do?

Comment: I've flagged the question for now. You can try flagging/contacting a moderator as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Observe that

$$a-\sqrt a=b-\sqrt b\implies a-b=\sqrt a-\sqrt b\iff\frac{(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)}{\sqrt a-\sqrt b}=1\iff$$

$$\iff \sqrt a+\sqrt b=1\;(\text{ assuming $\,a\neq b\,$)}\implies b=(1-\sqrt a)^2$$

So you need the maximum of $\;f(a):=a+b=a+(1-\sqrt a)^2=2a-2\sqrt a+1\;$ ...can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I see it now... $1+2(a- \sqrt{a})$ is always less than $1$ for $a<1$, which is why $a+b=1$ is the maximum. Fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$a+\sqrt b=b+\sqrt a\iff a-b=(\sqrt a+\sqrt b)(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)=\sqrt a-\sqrt b.$$

Then $a=b$ (which is not allowed) or $\sqrt a+\sqrt b=1$.

Now,

$$a+b=a+(1-\sqrt a)^2$$ has an extremum found by taking the derivative on $a$,

$$1-\frac{1-\sqrt a}{\sqrt a}=0$$

which gives $a=\dfrac14$. But it turns out that this is a minmum.

Then we also have to try the values at the boundaries of the domain: $a=0,b=1$ and $a=1,b=0$ both yield

$$a+b=1$$

which is the searched maximum.

Answer (score 1):

As
$$
a-b=(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})=\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}
$$
then with $a\ne b$ it gives $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=1$. Now you have to maximize 
$$
(\sqrt{a})^2+(\sqrt{b})^2
$$
subject to $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=1$.

Answer (score 1):

For $a\ne b,$

$$\sqrt a+\sqrt b=1$$

WLOG $a=\cos^4t,b=\sin^4t$

$$a+b=1-2\sin^2t\cos^2t=1-\dfrac{\sin^22t}2$$

Now $0\le\sin^22t\le1$

Or $a+b=1-\dfrac{1-\cos4t}4=\dfrac{3+\cos4t}4$

Now $-1\le\cos4t\le1$

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, let $b=ax,x\ge 0$. Then:
$$a+\sqrt{b} = b + \sqrt{a} \iff a+\sqrt{ax}=ax+\sqrt{a} \iff \\
\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{x}-1)=a(x-1) \stackrel{x\ne 1}{\iff} 1=\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{x}+1) \iff a=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x}+1)^2}.$$
Hence:
$$a+b=a+ax=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x}+1)^2}+\frac{x}{(\sqrt{x}+1)^2}=\frac{x+1}{(\sqrt{x}+1)^2}\le 1, x\ge 0.$$
Equality occurs for $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

$$
a = x^2\\
b = y^2
$$

the problem reads now

$$
\max (x^2+y^2)\;\;\mbox{s.t.}\;\; x^2-y^2=x-y\Rightarrow x+y=1
$$

now the problem is reduced to:

Find $r$ in $C\to x^2+y^2-r^2=0$ such that $C$ is tangent  to $x+y = 1$

Comment: By symmetry, this solution is such that $x=y$, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

A graph in this situation greatly helps.

Graphing the squared equation $(a-\sqrt a)^2=(b-\sqrt b)^2$ in the $aOb$ Cartesian plane gives a bean-like shape, touching the axes at $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. It can be verified that the upper-right part of the graph is an artifact of the squaring. Therefore the maximum point should occur at $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, since you can calculate the slope of the tangent line there to be zero and infinite, respectively.

However this is not a complete and rigorous solution. To complete it, you need to prove that $0\le a,b\le1$, which you've done so; and then you can demonstrate that the curve is concave upwards (when using the coordinate system $uOv$, where $u,v=a\pm b$), by calculating the implicit derivative. Finally you can conclude that the maximum value occurs at the endpoints.